# SQL Server Select most recent record (with a twist)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have the following table:

```
ActionDate                  ActionType
------------                ------------
2018-08-02 12:59:56.000     Drill
2018-08-02 13:20:45.000     Hammer
2018-08-02 14:36:02.000     Drill
```

I want to select the most recent ActionType based on the ActionDate.   This is not a problem using ROW_NUMBER() OVER syntax and either grabbing the first or last record depending on how I sorted.  However consider this table setup:

```
ActionDate                  ActionType
------------                ------------
2018-08-02 12:59:56.000     Drill
2018-08-02 13:20:45.000     
2018-08-02 14:36:02.000     Drill
```

In this case, since the only action listed is Drill, I want the oldest occurrence, since the Action didn't actually change.  Is there a way to satisfy both requirements at the same time?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be what ever ActionType is for max(date)? or are there more columns? In both cases the result should be Drill, correct?

Comment: Actually, I mis-stated, I want the ActionDate.  In the first example, I want the 14:36:02 newest and in the second, the 12:59:56 (oldest)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking for.  Clearly, you don't only have three rows.  Why is a blank type special?  What if there are multiple Drills on adjacent rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` with a `CASE` statement.

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
from YourTable
order by
    case 
        when (select count(distinct ActionType) from @table) = 1 
        then row_number() over (order by ActionDate asc) 
        else row_number() over (order by ActionDate desc)
    end
```

Or in a subquery if you like that better...

```
select ActionDate, ActionType
from
    (select
        *, 
        RN = case 
                when (select count(distinct ActionType) from @table) = 1 
                then row_number() over (order by ActionDate asc) 
                else row_number() over (order by ActionDate desc)
            end
    from YourTable) x
where RN = 1
```

This assume the blank is actually a `NULL` which is ignored in `COUNT DISTINCT`. If that is a blank space instead of `NULL` then you need to handle that with an additional `CASE` or `IIF` or whatever like this:

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
from YourTable
order by
    case 
        when (select count(distinct case when ActionType = '' then null else ActionType end) from @table) = 1 
        then row_number() over (order by ActionDate asc) 
        else row_number() over (order by ActionDate desc)
    end
```